# Show that, if $f ' (x) = 1$ then $f(x) = x + C$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

> Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(a, b)$.
>
> Show that, if $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x \in (a, b)$, then there exists a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x + C$ for all $x ∈ (a, b)$.

Initially I was going to let $f(x)=y$ then integrate it like a differential equation but my teacher said that wasn't allowed. Could I prove that the differential of $f(x)= x + C$ is equal to 1 ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
&\frac{dy}{dx} = 1\\
&\frac{y}{x} = 1 \ \ \ \ \text{Cancel the d's}\\
&y = x.
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Jahambo99 Is this a joke?!

Comment: All is well people! It is of course a joke.

Comment: @Jahambo99: does it work when $d=0$ ?

Comment: Yves Daust, unlike Jahambo99's, your joke is funny.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what your teacher has in mind.  It's clear that if f(x) = x + C then f'(x) = 1. and by the fundamental theorem of calculus you *can* integrate.  So I guess the idea is to go through the mechanics FTC for an example.

Answer (score 8):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$. What can you say about $g'(x)$? Apply the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& 1 \\ \\
\mathrm dy &=& \mathrm dx \\ \\
\int \mathrm dy &=& \int \mathrm dx \\ \\
y &=& x+ C
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: OP said he cannot "integrate it like a differential equation". This therefore does not answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

the slope of the curve is given to be 1

f$^{'}$$\left(x\right)$=1.$\forall$x$\epsilon(a,b)$
i.e., slope is unchanged at every point of the curve

equation of the curve with slope m and passing from $\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)$is
y-y$_{1}$=m$\left(x-x_{1}\right)$.

m=1$\Longrightarrow$y-y$_{1}$=x-x$_{1}$$\Longrightarrow$y=x+$\left(-y_{1}+x_{1}\right)$.

let$\left\{ y_{1}-x_{1}\right\} $=c$\Longrightarrow$y=x+c

Comment: So every function that has a derivative is a line?

Comment: if a function is differentiable at point, then a tangent with unique and finite slope can be drawn at that point

Comment: particularly in this question,slope remains unchanged at every point of the curve,that is only possible if curve is nothing but some straight line.

Comment: "slope remains unchanged at every point of the curve"  I don't see where you indicated or made use of this in your answer.  The derivative of all (differentiable) functions is a slope at that point.

Comment: @fleablood one may ask why i selected the equation of line for putting the value of m.the answer comes from this statement.This statement tells that curve is nothing but a straight line.